# GDB: pthread_cond_wait.S: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, join, gdb, boost-thread

I am trying to join the thread using boost and the program seems to wait indefinitely when I do that.

`Thread->join();`

On the console I see the following output when I break.

`Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:185
185     ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S: No such file or directory.`

Here is the `GDB trace.`

`#0  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:185`

`#1  0x00000000004900a3 in boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&) () at /usr/local/boost/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:73`

`#2  0x00007ffff724e333 in boost::thread::join_noexcept() () at libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp:316`

`#3  0x000000000048e135 in LIN::waitForThreads() () at /usr/local/boost/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:767`

`#4  0x00000000004882fd in fa::testinit::test_method() () at /home/ubuntu/UnitTest01.cpp:205`

`#5  0x0000000000488ef1 in fa::testinit_invoker() () at /home/ubuntu/UnitTest01.cpp:173`

`#6  0x000000000047296b in boost::detail::function::function_obj_invoker0<boost::detail::forward, int>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&) ()
    at /usr/local/boost/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:771`

`#7  0x000000000044aabd in boost::execution_monitor::catch_signals(boost::function<int ()> const&) () at /usr/local/boost/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:771`

`#8  0x000000000044ab91 in boost::execution_monitor::execute(boost::function<int ()> const&) () at /usr/local/boost/include/boost/test/impl/execution_monitor.ipp:1207`

`#9  0x000000000044b2d5 in boost::execution_monitor::vexecute(boost::function<void ()> const&) () at /usr/local/boost/include/boost/test/impl/execution_monitor.ipp:1313`

`#10 0x0000000000452bb2 in boost::unit_test::unit_test_monitor_t::execute_and_translate(boost::function<void ()> const&, unsigned int) () at /usr/local/boost/include/boost/test/impl/unit_test_monitor.ipp:46`

`#11 0x0000000000484760 in boost::unit_test::framework::state::execute_test_tree(unsigned long, unsigned int) () at /usr/local/boost/include/boost/test/impl/framework.ipp:685`

`#12 0x00000000004849ac in boost::unit_test::framework::state::execute_test_tree(unsigned long, unsigned int) () at /usr/local/boost/include/boost/test/impl/framework.ipp:636`

`#13 0x0000000000460329 in boost::unit_test::framework::run(unsigned long, bool) () at /usr/local/boost/include/boost/test/impl/framework.ipp:636`

`#14 0x0000000000460957 in boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(boost::unit_test::test_suite* (*)(int, char**), int, char**) () at usr/local/boost/include/boost/test/impl/unit_test_main.ipp:228`

`#15 0x00007ffff6673aed in __libc_start_main (main=0x4419c0 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe6c8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe6b8) at libc-start.c:269`

`#16 0x0000000000442ec9 in _start () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:122`

waitForThreads code :

`{
    stopthread = true;
    //wait for Thread 2
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(thread2_lock);
    lock.unlock();
    m_ConditionVariable.notify_one();
    m_Thread->join();
}`

Thread 2 code:

`while(!stopthread){ 
     boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(thread2_lock); 
     while (m_Queue.empty())
     { 
         m_ConditionVariable.wait(lock);
     } 
    if (!m_Queue.empty()){ 
        struct queue_output out; 
        out = m_Queue.front();
        m_Queue.pop_front(); 
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock new_lock(another_lock);
        if (write(fd, &out, sizeof(struct queue_output)) == -1) 
            close(out.fd); 
    } 
}`

code to update queue:
`{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(thread2_lock);
    m_Queue.push_back(input);
    lock.unlock();
    m_ConditionVariable.notify_one();
}`

In UnitTest01.cpp, testinit first I am creating the thread, then updating the queue, then calling join.

Can someone please help me understand why it is hanging while thread joining?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just before this thread join, there is another thread join which works perfectly. This join is on the second thread. So altogether there are 3 threads (main thread, first thread on which join exits gracefully and second thread on which join hangs)

Comment: What is that second thread doing?

Comment: It is monitoring a queue.

Comment: But is it exiting? The `join()` won't return until that thread exits.

Comment: It does this

` while(!stopthread) {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(thread2_lock);
            while (m_Queue.empty()) {
                m_ConditionVariable.wait(lock);
            }
            if (!m_Queue.empty()) {
                struct queue_output out;
                out = m_Queue.front();
                m_Queue.pop_front();
                boost::mutex::scoped_lock new_lock(another_lock);
                if (write(fd, &out, sizeof(struct queue_output)) == -1)
                    close(out.fd);
            }
        }`

Comment: So if the `m_Queue` is empty, it will never stop.  Therefore  the `join()` will never unblock.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
But as a work around  I updated the queue with single entry and notify the `thread2_lock `before I call thread `join`. Also set `stopthread` to true. This will happen in main thread.
So when thread 2 gets notified it will come out of first if loop and proceed to next if loop and do the processing.
After that when it reaches while loop, the condition is false hence should exit.

Comment: You should post code in your question - it's very hard to reason about multiple threads with imprecise language.

Comment: @mooli Perhaps you did something wrong in your new code ? Or perhaps you set stopthread too late, after your thread has processed the message ?

Comment: @nos How can I check whether thread 2 has processed it? I know that there is some synchronization error due to which the thread is not exiting, but not able to figure out where.